# Can unused USB Type C pins be shorted together?

Tags: voltage, current, usb, connector, usb-device

[image]

Can the unused USB Type C connector pins be shorted together?

Can someone please verify if my terminations for the connector pins are correct or do they require modifications?

Comment: why would you want to short them together from the first place?

Comment: This is my first attempt and was not sure what to do with the unused pins. Hence shorted them. @ChristianidisVasileios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's not advisable to short them together.

Leave them unconnected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please tell me what happens if I short them together? Should I also remove the protection termination diodes too?

Comment: As stated in my answer, if you have no use of them then just leave unconnected. You don't have to place any protection device. And as for shorting RX, TX and SBU pins together, this may cause some electrical damage to the device at the other end. You don't know if the other side has protections against such cases.

Comment: Thank you. Apart from this, the ground terminations are fine, right? So, I will modify as you said, by leaving all the shorted pins, floating.

Comment: Yes, ground terminations should be done. No problems with those.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!